# convert string array of byte values to a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a textbox on a form where a person types in a byte array into in the format shown below.

My question is how can I then convert the string array produced into a byte array of the same values?

so this would be entered into the text box :

```
0x11, 0x01, 0x49, 0x4D, 0x41, 0x47, 0x45, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x53, 0x75, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x72, 0x79, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

the following code then splits it and converts it to a byte array

```
string text = txtChecksumText.Text;
        string[] parts = text.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[parts.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(parts[i], 16); // this isn't working as expected
            txtResponse.Text += Environment.NewLine + "     " + i + " = " + parts[i] + " = " + bytes[i].ToString() ;
        }
```

and the response to show it isn't working

```
 0 = 0x11 = 17
 1 = 0x01 = 1
 2 = 0x49 = 73
 3 = 0x4D = 77
 4 = 0x41 = 65
 5 = 0x47 = 71
 6 = 0x45 = 69
 7 = 0x31 = 49
 8 = 0x00 = 0
 9 = 0x00 = 0
 10 = 0x00 = 0
 11 = 0x00 = 0
 12 = 0x00 = 0
 13 = 0x00 = 0
 14 = 0x00 = 0
 15 = 0x00 = 0
 16 = 0x00 = 0
 17 = 0x00 = 0
 18 = 0x00 = 0
 19 = 0x00 = 0
 20 = 0x00 = 0
 21 = 0x00 = 0
 22 = 0x00 = 0
 23 = 0x01 = 1
 24 = 0x53 = 83
 25 = 0x75 = 117
 26 = 0x6D = 109
 27 = 0x6D = 109
 28 = 0x61 = 97
 29 = 0x72 = 114
 30 = 0x79 = 121
 31 = 0x00 = 0
 32 = 0x00 = 0
 33 = 0x00 = 0
 34 = 0x00 = 0
 35 = 0x00 = 0
 36 = 0x00 = 0
 37 = 0x00 = 0
 38 = 0x00 = 0
 39 = 0x00 = 0
 40 = 0x00 = 0
 41 = 0x00 = 0
 42 = 0x00 = 0
 43 = 0x00 = 0
 44 = 0x00 = 0
 45 = 0x00 = 0
 46 = 0x00 = 0
 47 = 0x00 = 0
 48 = 0x00 = 0
 49 = 0x00 = 0
 50 = 0x00 = 0
 51 = 0x00 = 0
 52 = 0x00 = 0
 53 = 0x00 = 0
 54 = 0x00 = 0
 55 = 0x00 = 0
```

Just to be clear, the 0x11 should come back as a byte 11 not byte 17, same with all the others I'm not trying to convert to decimal i'm trying to convert the string of literal bytes to a byte array for check-sum creation

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what aren't working? It seems to be working fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Is the problem that for example 0x45 gets converted to 69? That is because 0x45 (45 hexadecimal is in fact 69 in decimal)

Comment: the 0x11 should come back as a byte 11 not byte 17, same with all the others I'm not trying to convert to decimal i'm trying to convert the string of literal bytes to a byte array for checksum creation

Comment: If you want 0x11 to be 11 not 17, what on earth do you want 0x6D to be?

Comment: @Rawling simple 6D! the string itself IS byte values! 0x6D should come back as a byte of 6D

Comment: and 0x11 _is_ a byte of 11... in hexadecimal. The only issue here is your `bytes[i].ToString()` is _writing_ the byte out in decimal... The byte itself doesn't have any concept of decimal or hex, it's in binary.

Comment: @Rawling many thanks you pointed me in the right direction I should have used the bitconverter, somehow missed that, re-post your comment as an answer and i'll mark it as accepted answer

Comment: Have done. Glad to clear up this for you...

Comment: @Rawling thanks for that have accepted, just wish people would stop downvoting the question its a valid question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytes you're getting are just bytes; they aren't intrinsically decimal or hexadecimal.

If you want to pass the bytes to something else (for a checksum), they're fine.

Your only problem is that you're writing them to the console in decimal form - use `ToString("x")` if you wish to write them out in hexadecimal form for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following:

```
txtHexString.Text="0x11, 0x01, 0x49, 0x4D, 0x41, 0x47, 0x45, 0x31, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x53, 0x75, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x72, 0x79, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00";

string[] namesArray =  txtHexString.Text.Split(',');
byte[] abc= new byte [namesArray.Length];

for (int i = 0; i <= namesArray.Length - 1; i = i + 1)
        {
            abc[i] = Convert.ToByte(namesArray[i].Replace(" ", ""), 16);
        }
```

here, abc is the desired byte array. Now do what ever you want with abc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. Chesk this to observe different conversions and choose whatever you need:

```
MessageBox.Show(11.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(11.ToString("x"));
MessageBox.Show(0x11.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(0x11.ToString("x"));
MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(new byte[] { 11, 0x11, 16 }));
```